# Looking for a secure method to hold private files for a given user

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I'm looking for a secure way to allow users to upload files (e.g. PDF) allowing for future access (by that user) while **denying access to anyone else**.

The user is authenticated using a standard account-creation/login process and their credentials are held in session (using Linux/Apache/MySql/Php).

Questions:

---

**Where should the files be held?**

1) I could create a directory for each user (upon account creation) and make the directory name a salted hash. Would that be secure way to do it?

OR

2) Should I put the uploaded files in a location on the server outside the webroot and move the files to a temp location for display to the user? (then destroy that file and that temp location after the user is done with it).

**(assuming choice #1 above) I would plan to create an .htaccess file for each directory with the following:**

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

**Would that be sufficient security for the given directory or is more needed?**

Platform:
* Shared server using LAMP stack (PHP 7.0+)

---

### Update:

I found a good discussion regarding this issue:

[Arguments for and against putting files outside of webroot](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial)

Seems the argument against using .htaccess to protect webroot files is:

### update (cont)

- so far the only argument I found against using .htaccess is:

> Imagine your server defaults for a virtual host are: no PHP, no
>   .htaccess, allow from all (hardly unusual in a production
>   environment). If your configuration is somehow reset during a routine
>   operation – like, say, a panel update – everything will revert to its
>   default state, and you're exposed.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603901/secure-way-to-store-files-in-web-server

Comment: Option 3. Put the files in a non-public location and when a user requests a file run PHP code to verify the user can access the file and send the file using [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Yea, I kind of like Anthony Rutledge answer on stackoverflow.com/questions/4603901 ... but it only got 1 vote!

Comment: apokryfos, would you create a unique "non-public location" for each user? If so, any thoughts on the method for creating the unique directory name?

Comment: Well usually you'd have a user provide something unique that identifies them so they'd use it to sign in, like an email or nickname or phone number. You could just use that since the directories are not public.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't directly state it, but since you're mentioning .htaccess, i assume the protocol you want to do file transfers over is http, using php and apache?

> Where should the files be held?

have a folder dedicated to user-folders, make sure that folder is outside of the web-root, and give each individual user their own dedicated folder inside the user-folders folder.

> 1) I could create a directory for each user (upon account creation) and make the directory name a salted hash. Would that be secure way to do it?

you said `The user is authenticated using a standard account-creation/login process and their credentials are held in session.`, i assume each user has their own dedicated id? usually a SQL PRIMARY KEY unique id? if yes, that id is already guaranteed to be unique, there is no need to have the directory name be a salted hash, just have the directory name be the user id, that will make everything easier (implementation, debugging, maintenance, disk-usage-logistics)

and.. have a php script that does file indexing and file transferring, and when people request to download a file, make sure to have strict file validation, you need to validate that the file requested is indeed located inside a folder that the requestee actually has permission to access the requested file, otherwise you'll get hackers requesting other people's files, or hackers requesting `/users-folder/user_1387/../../../../etc/passwd` or similar (you can use realpath() + strpos() for such validation).

.and because Apache is MUCH better at file transfer than php is, once a file has been requested for download AND has been validated, you should use X-Sendfile or similar to actually do the file transfer, apache will be able to transfer the file much more efficiently than php.. (and if for whatever reason you can't use X-Sendfile, then check the php passthru() function, but it gets more complex if you intend to support streaming/content-range/stuff like that, which is difficult and inefficient to do in PHP but easy for apache)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am using php to transfer the files via https. Overall, I was looking for a solid reason why an .htaccess protected directory is less secure than a directory outside the webroot. Opinions seem to vary rather widely on the issue (see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial).